# Doctrine remove "()" automatically

Tags: doctrine

When I built a query, the doctrine removed the "()" automatically.

Here is my query:

```
$query = MstFontTable::getInstance()->createQuery('msf');
$query->where('(full_font_name LIKE ? OR
                full_font_name LIKE ? OR
                full_font_name LIKE ? OR
                full_font_name = ? OR
                font_name = ?)', array(trim($fontName) . ',%',
                                       '%,' . trim($fontName),
                                       '%,' . trim($fontName) . ',%',
                                       trim($fontName),
                                       trim($fontName)
                                      )
             );
$query->andWhere('((tenant_id = 0 OR tenant_id = ?))', array(intval($tenantId)));
```

Here is the result when I use $query->getDql():

```
FROM MstFont msf WHERE (full_font_name LIKE ? OR
                full_font_name LIKE ? OR
                full_font_name LIKE ? OR
                full_font_name = ? OR
                font_name = ?) AND ((tenant_id = 0 OR tenant_id = ?))
```

Here is the result when I use $query->getSqlQuery():

```
SELECT m.font_id AS m__font_id, m.tenant_id AS m__tenant_id, m.font_name AS m__font_name, m.font_file AS m__font_file, m.font_category AS m__font_category, m.vendor AS m__vendor, m.full_font_name AS m__full_font_name, m.font_name_ap AS m__font_name_ap FROM mst_font m WHERE (m.full_font_name LIKE ? OR
                full_font_name LIKE ? OR
                full_font_name LIKE ? OR
                full_font_name = ? OR
                font_name = ? AND (m.tenant_id = 0 OR m.tenant_id = ?))
```

Has anyone help me explain this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing excess brackets like:

```
$query->andWhere('((tenant_id = 0 OR tenant_id = ?))', array(intval($tenantId)));
```

to

```
$query->andWhere('tenant_id = 0 OR tenant_id = ?', array(intval($tenantId)));
```

Do the same for first one too like from:

```
$query->where('(full_font_name LIKE ? OR ...
```

to

```
$query->where('full_font_name LIKE ? OR ...
```

and see what happens. You don't need them and Doctrine will put brackets for those and/or conditions.